# Sitemap.xml для поисковой выдачи яндекса

Tags: яндекс-поиск

Что нужно сделать, чтобы поисковая выдача моего сайта в яндексе выглядела бы так:

http://s020.radikal.ru/i717/1406/bd/39b0ba364959.jpg

Я имею ввиду надписи по-русски. Там пишется вроде бы свой `sitemap.xml` специально для яндекса, но какой формат файла я так и не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [микроданные](https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4598337?hl=ru&ref_topic=3309300) и, как верно заметил klopp, сходите по ссылке на скриншоте и почитайте секцию "оформление результатов поиска".

Answer (score 1):

1. Файл `sitemap.xml` на то, что появляется в результатах поиска, не влияен никак вообще. Он только задаёт страницы для индексирования, сообщает роботу про врмя их обновления и про приоритеты. Остальное зависит от конкретного поисковика.
2. Накакого спецформата для Яндекса не существует, они ещё пока достаточно вменяемы, чтобы иметь дело с общепринятыми стандартами.
3. Обо всём этом, и о многом другом, можно было бы узнать самостоятельно, по ссылкам, которые находятся (сюрприз!) на скриншоте, приведённом в вопросе. [Например](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/indexing-options/sitemap.xml).